# Deno: How to allow read permission for directory/folder

Tags: deno

Looking at https://deno.land/manual/examples/file_system_events
which is the code below.

```
const watcher = Deno.watchFs("./src");
for await (const event of watcher) {
  console.log(">>>> event", event);
  // { kind: "create", paths: [ "/foo.txt" ] }
}
```

However, when I try to `--allow-read` permissions I get the `error: Is a directory`

```
deno run --allow-read src/  main.ts
error: Is a directory (os error 21)
```

How do I ensure that the explicit permission `--allow-read` is permitted for the specified `/src` folder?

I know that I can use `-A` to `--allow-all`, however, I want to be explicit to the allowed permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I found the problem. Well first of all you need to use a `=` to add the allowed paths, like so:

```sh
deno run --allow-read=src/ main.ts
```

But it'll still won't work and it seems to be a bug/enhancement.

On your script you need to provide the **absolute path** and then it will be effective:

```js
const watcher = Deno.watchFs("<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/src");
```

For me it's an issue on the `Deno.watchFs()` method and I opened up one on Github:

https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/5742

Comment: Thanks for this - I also understand taht I can use `--allow-read` without explicitly setting any args - but this is also interesting to note - thanks